# {file-name} download failed due to an unknown error when file HAS DOWNLOADED SUCCESSFULLY

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, blob

I'm trying to download a PDF file by creating a Blob link for the data received from a PHP (Laravel) server on Chrome for Android. Chrome for Android shows 'downloading...' and then shows the error message '{file-name} download failed due to an unknown error'. But when I go to downloads in Chrome for Android, the file is listed there and opens as well. Same is the case in local file system.

I wonder why Chrome for Android is showing error when the file has downloaded properly ? Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: You're using the FileReader API to `.readAsArrayBuffer`? Question is unclear. If you don't want the Browser to execute the file, consider a zip.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as well, file was downloaded yet it was giving me error "download failed due to unknown error"

I fixed it by downgrading my chrome app.

Issue was on Chrome v58, and I downgraded it to v51 and it fixed my issue.

Comment: I tried this on chrome v57.* on Android 7 and Android 6. it doesn't show error in Android 6 but does so in Android 7. Strange things

Comment: Yes, I think its compatibility issue of Google Chrome with Android. :)
You need lower version of google chrome for higher version of android. Inversely proportion :)